# Full height of a html element (div) including border, padding and margin?

Tags: javascript, css

I need the full height of a div, I'm currently using

```
document.getElementById('measureTool').offsetHeight
```

> `offsetHeight` - Returns the height of an element, including borders and padding if any, but not margins

But one of the nested elements inside the div, has a `margin-top` of `20%`, so I get a wrong measurement. I tried `style.marginTop` and `scrollHeight` without success.

How can I get the full height (border, padding, margin) of an element (div) in javascript?

If there isn't any other way I'm ok with jQuery.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you can use jQuery:

```
$('#divId').outerHeight(true) // gives with margins.
```

[**jQuery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

For vanilla javascript you need to write a lot more (like always...):

```
function Dimension(elmID) {
    var elmHeight, elmMargin, elm = document.getElementById(elmID);
    if(document.all) {// IE
        elmHeight = elm.currentStyle.height;
        elmMargin = parseInt(elm.currentStyle.marginTop, 10) + parseInt(elm.currentStyle.marginBottom, 10) + "px";
    } else {// Mozilla
        elmHeight = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, '').getPropertyValue('height');
        elmMargin = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, '').getPropertyValue('margin-top')) + parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, '').getPropertyValue('margin-bottom')) + "px";
    }
    return (elmHeight+elmMargin);
}
```

​
[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rA6Cb/)

[code source](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-45522.html)

Comment: I would very much prefer not to (the project isnt really a webpage). But thanks for the jquery solution and fast reply! :)

Comment: Traversing the whole DOM with getElementById every time is bad code, and waste of cpu time, and also more code. Edited your answer, caching the elm in a variable.

Comment: The above code does not appear to work in the case that OP asked about. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3e2y1j0s/1/. (Adding a 1px padding doubles the reported height.)

Comment: Also, note that jQuery can report an outerHeight that ignores the top-margin of the first child and the bottom-margin of the last child - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770248/div-height-with-child-margin/28121477#28121477.

Comment: the non-jquery solution gets the element's content height + both margins, but ignores padding and border (and eventual scrollbars) http://jsfiddle.net/3e2y1j0s/3/

Comment: This solution assumes the margins are only ever defined in pixel units.  For any margins NOT defined in pixel units, it will return incorrect results.

Comment: Mind that for some reason `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` over elements are EXTREMELY slow on Android.

Comment: px aside, this Vanilla JS example was superb "above and beyond" territory.

Answer (score 116):

What about something like this (no jquery)? It's similar to @gdoron's answer but a little simpler. Tested it in IE9+, Firefox, and Chrome.

```
function getAbsoluteHeight(el) {
  // Get the DOM Node if you pass in a string
  el = (typeof el === 'string') ? document.querySelector(el) : el; 

  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  var margin = parseFloat(styles['marginTop']) +
               parseFloat(styles['marginBottom']);

  return Math.ceil(el.offsetHeight + margin);
}
```

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7926G/2/).

Answer (score 29):

```
var el = document.querySelector('div');

var elHeight = el.offsetHeight;
elHeight += parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('margin-top'));
elHeight += parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));

console.log(elHeight);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gbd47ox1/

I think this solution is more readable, but none of the solutions presented account for sizes that aren't pixels... :(

Comment: It seems to get the computed height (in pixels) correctly when I set the height in `em`?

Comment: Maybe. I'd test that in various browsers though since they all have different subpixel rounding techniques.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a slight optimisation to this solution:

    ```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    function getElementHeight(el) {
        const $elComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(el);
        return el.offsetHeight + parseInt($elComputedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-top') + $elComputedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'), 10);
    }
    ```

Answer (score 16):

Another functional solution using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
let el = document.querySelector('div');
let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
let height = ['height', 'padding-top', 'padding-bottom']
        .map((key) => parseInt(style.getPropertyValue(key), 10))
        .reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur);
```

Comment: You might wanna add `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`

Comment: Heads up, paddings are already included within the style height, but you'll probably need to add margins as suggested.

Comment: Don't consider calculating `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the total height as it's already added to `height` and calculating it again will give you wrong total height.

Answer (score 15):

qdev wrote a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490646/5950626), however I think offsetHeight is faster and better supported than getBoundingClientRect(). I also used ES6 to reduce the code size.

```
/**
 * Returns the element height including margins
 * @param element - element
 * @returns {number}
 */
function outerHeight(element) {
    const height = element.offsetHeight,
        style = window.getComputedStyle(element)

    return ['top', 'bottom']
        .map(side => parseInt(style[`margin-${side}`]))
        .reduce((total, side) => total + side, height)
}
```

Comment: I really like this Style @fabian-von-ellerts I slightly modified it and put it into my helper Collection. I hope that's okay?

Comment: @Raphael Thanks! Sure, I did the same hahaha

Answer (score 12):

Use all the props, margin, border, padding and height in sequence.

```js
function getElmHeight(node) {
    const list = [
        'margin-top',
        'margin-bottom',
        'border-top',
        'border-bottom',
        'padding-top',
        'padding-bottom',
        'height'
    ]

    const style = window.getComputedStyle(node)
    return list
        .map(k => parseInt(style.getPropertyValue(k), 10))
        .reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur)
}
```

Comment: the parseInt radix argument is not getting set correctly. I tried to edit your answer but edits have to change at least 6 characters :/

Comment: alright sure, `.map(k => parseInt(style.getPropertyValue(k)), 10)` should be `.map(k => parseInt(style.getPropertyValue(k), 10))`

Answer (score 11):

Vanilla JavaScript ECMAScript 5.1

- [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://caniuse.com/#feat=getBoundingClientRect) returns a DOMRect object which contains `height` (including `padding` & `border`)
- [window.getComputedStyle(element)](https://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle) returns an object with all CSS properties after applying active stylesheets and performed any computation (if present)

```js
var element = document.getElementById('myID'),
    height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    
// height: element height + vertical padding & borders
// now we just need to add vertical margins
height = ["top", "bottom"]
  .map(function(side) {
    return parseInt(style['margin-' + side], 10)
  })
  .reduce(function(total, side) {
    return total + side
  }, height)
  
// result: compare with devtools computed measurements
document.querySelector('.result').innerText = 'Total height is: ' + height + 'px';
```

```css
#myID {
  padding: 10px 0 20px;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-bottom: solid 3px pink;
  margin: 5px 0 7px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID">element</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

old one - anyway... for all jQuery-banning and shortcut folks out there here is some plus scripting which expands the dimension/getabsoluteheight approaches of the other answers:

```
function getallinheight(obj) {
  var compstyle=(typeof window.getComputedStyle==='undefined')?obj.currentStyle:window.getComputedStyle(obj);
  var marginTop=parseInt(compstyle.marginTop);
  var marginBottom=parseInt(compstyle.marginBottom);
  var borderTopWidth=parseInt(compstyle.borderTopWidth);
  var borderBottomWidth=parseInt(compstyle.borderBottomWidth);
  return obj.offsetHeight+
         (isNaN(marginTop)?0:marginTop)+(isNaN(marginBottom)?0:marginBottom)+
         (isNaN(borderTopWidth)?0:borderTopWidth)+(isNaN(borderBottomWidth)?0:borderBottomWidth);
}
alert(getallinheight(document.getElementById('measureTool')));
```

Answer (score 5):

The earlier solutions are probably ideal. In search of an easy way, I came up with something like that. This wraps the target in a `div`. The height of the `div` is already calculated and rounded.

```
<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;">
    <p class="target">something info ex</p>
</div>
```

and in JavaScript:

```
var height = document.querySelector(".target").parentElement.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Far, far simpler if you have control over the HTML.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in Vanilla JS
in the function getAllmargin we get the sum of both margin top and bottom 
and with clientHeight we get the height including all paddings

```
var measureTool = document.getElementById('measureTool');
function getAllmargin(elem){
//Use parseInt method to get only number
        return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('margin-top')) 
        + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
}
//Finally we get entire height  
console.log(measureTool.clientHeight + getAllmargin(measureTool));
```