# Preserving scroll position while inserting div, but only when user has scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a container `div` that is used for displaying log messages. I prepend each message as a separate child `div` element when it is generated. The parent `div` is set to `overlay-y:auto` such that after the message elements exceed the height of the parent container, it scrolls. The behavior I'm trying to produce is that messages scroll as normal, except that if the user scrolls down through the "history" of the messages they don't scroll/move out of the visible area of the parent `div` when new messages are prepended to the top of the message list.

My current attempt looks like this:

**html:**

```
<div id='log'>
  <h4>Log</h4>
  <div id='log-rows'></div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
log: function(text) {
  var messageHTML = "<div><span class='timestamp'>" + (new Date()).toISOString() + "</span> - <span class='message'>" + text + "</span></div>";

  this.$el.find("#log-rows").prepend(messageHTML);

  var firstLogMessage = $('#log-rows').children().first();

  $('#log-rows').children().each( function(index, row) {
    row.scrollTop += firstLogMessage.height();
  });

  ...
}
```

**css:**

```
#log-rows {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: How can a user "scroll off screen"?

Comment: @RacilHilan: good point, my language wasn't clear. basically I don't want the div I've scrolled to, to move when I prepend a new line to the parent's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `log` function. This works for me:

```
function log(text) {
  var messageHTML = "<div><span class='timestamp'>" + (new Date()).toISOString() + "</span> - <span class='message'>" + text + "</span></div>";

  $("#log").find("#log-rows").prepend(messageHTML);

  var scrollTop = $("#log-rows").scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop > 0) {
    var childHeight = $("#log-rows div").outerHeight(true); // get's the new element's full height including margin
    var scrollDelta =  scrollTop + childHeight;
    $("#log-rows").scrollTop(scrollDelta);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just noting that `.outerHeight(true)` is better to use than `.height` since it includes padding, borders and optionally margin. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787782/full-height-of-a-html-element-div-including-border-padding-and-margin