# Scrolling Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, progress-bar, scrolltop

What I'm trying to do is implement a progress bar to indicate how close one is to the end of the page in **vanilla JavaScript.** However, I'm running into a few issues.

First of all, although the `body` element is being scrolled, `document.body.scrollTop` always returns `0`. I've sorted this out by using `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`.

It's been a while since I last implemented a feature like this, so I took to Stack Overflow and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787782/full-height-of-a-html-element-div-including-border-padding-and-margin), which jogged my memory a bit. From what I remember about the last time I implemented this feature, the formula should be something like the following, which was mentioned in that thread.

```
const progressBar = document.getElementById('footer__progress_bar')
const totalValue = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight

document.body.onscroll = () => {
  let currentValue = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop
  let offset = (currentValue / totalValue) * 100 - 100 + '%'
  progressBar.style.left = offset
}
```

Unfortunately something is off with the script above and I can't seem to figure out what it is. For some reason the value of `offset` overshoots (and sometimes undershoots) the mark. I've created a **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/qYKLBe?editors=1111)** and the overshoot problem is persisting, so it seems as if the issue is the formula itself. Nonetheless, when I look at the numbers (window.innerHeight, body.scrollTop, et cetera), none of them seem to add up. Below are the numbers.

```
window.innerHeight ..................... 779
document.body.clientHeight ............ 3210
document.body.offsetHeight ............ 3212
document.body.scrollTop .................. 0
document.scrollingElement.scrollTop ... 2646
```

I've also noticed some super strange behaviour. `document.body.clientHeight` and `document.body.offsetHeight` will randomly change values when I refresh the page, so that they're almost constantly jumping back and forth from `X to Y`.

Notably, the body element itself has a `height` of `auto` and no vertical margins, albeit some of its children do have vertical margins. The `main` element, which is where I'm embedding everything from the database, also has `height: auto`, yet it also returns `0` when I check its `scrollTop`.

**Does anybody have any idea where I'm going wrong or why the numbers aren't adding up?**

Comment: The formula or the onScroll function seems to be correct. However, nos. you have shared does not seem to match i.e document.scrollingElement.scrollTop (max value) === document.body.scrollHeight (or offsetHeight) - window.innerHeight

Comment: @KishanR Thanks for responding. I'm having troubles understanding what you said after  "The formula or the onScroll function seems to be correct."

Answer (score 3):

Please see the changes I have applied to your CODEPEN

```css
body {
 height: 300vh;
 background: black
}

footer {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #fff
}

#footer__progress_bar {
 height: 20px;
 background: blue;
 width: 0%;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <div id="footer__progress_bar">0%</div>
</footer>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() { ScrollIndicator() };

function ScrollIndicator() {
 var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
 document.getElementById( 'footer__progress_bar' ).style.width = scrolled + "%";
 document.getElementById( 'footer__progress_bar' ).innerHTML = Math.round( scrolled ) + "%"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. It's working... I'm wondering where I personally went wrong. I'll have a good look at this after I finish watching this TV show

Comment: it works. i'm baffled. they broke the old formula. i never remember having to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`, and `document.documenntElement.clientHeight`

Comment: i just noticed your version is also overshooting the mark the too. it's just less noticeable because i'm altering the `width` as oppose to the `left` offset

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem, please?

Comment: i placed all of the variables inside the function and it's working like charm now. i had moved one of the variables outside of the function, which i believe was messing it up

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**PrognRoll**](https://github.com/mburakerman/prognroll) jQuery plugin:

**Examples**

Body demo on **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzArK)**

```
<body>
<!-- Content -->
</body>
```

Display a scroll progress indicator:

```
$(function() {
  $("body").prognroll();
});
```

or create a scroll indicator with CSS and JavaScript (without plugin).

See the live example below:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  ScrollIndicator()
};

function ScrollIndicator() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("headerBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
  console.log(Math.round(scrolled * 100) / 100);
  document.getElementById("footerBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
  document.getElementById("footerBar").innerHTML = Math.round(scrolled) + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
  width: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.footer-progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
  width: 0%;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="headerBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Scroll down to see how it works</h2>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="footer-progress-bar" id="footerBar">0%</div>
</footer>
```