# How to do line animation under a navbar on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When we scroll in some websites there is a line animation under the navigation bar how to make it?

I found a website that uses that animation like [here](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/what-is-localhost#:%7E:text=Usually%2C%20you%20can%20access%20the,requests%20the%20IP%20address%20127.0.)

I search it many times on youtube and google but didn't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323483/scrolling-progress-bar

Comment: We don't know how to check your problem, a simple code/s or screenshots will help us. Try to read [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your quesiton?

```js
const elem = document.querySelector(".scrolling");
let maxScroll = elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight; //최대 스크롤값
document.querySelector("#maxScroll").innerHTML = maxScroll;

elem.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {  
  let scroll = elem.scrollTop / maxScroll;  
  elem.style.setProperty("--scroll", scroll);    
  document.querySelector("#nowScroll").innerHTML = scroll + " (" +parseInt(scroll * 100) + "% )";
});
```

```css
.scrolling{
  border:solid 1px blue;  
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink calc(100% * var(--scroll)), white 0);
  background-size:100% 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling">
  You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
    You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
    You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
    You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
  You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
    You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
    You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
    You may have heard about CSS Variables (aka CSS Custom Properties), but think it’s not something you can use yet. Plus, you already have your preprocessor pipeline in place, why should you care? This talk will show how CSS Variables are much more powerful than static preprocessor variables and can be used today without compromising progressive enhancement. You will also learn several creative tips and tricks to take full advantage of them. As is customary with Lea’s CSS talks, expect a swath of live demos to demonstrate the material.
</div>

<div>
  최대 스크롤 값 : <span id="maxScroll"></span><br/>
  현재 스크롤 : <span id="nowScroll"></span><br/>
</div>
```