# Jquery scroll animation scrolles to bottom of div instead of top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website whit a nav bar. When item in navbar is clicked it should scroll to the specific div. but it scrolls to the bottom of the div instead of the top.

I can't find the mistake can someone help me?

Any help is welcome.

My Code:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #10171e;
  color: white;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #15202b;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.header-right {
  float: left;
}

.home{
  /*margin-bottom: 500px;*/
}
.about{
  background: red;
  /*height: 1000px;*/
  /*margin-top: 500px;*/
  /*margin-bottom: 500px;*/
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.contact{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1000px;
  /*margin-top: 500px;*/
  /*margin-bottom: 500px;*/
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <title>Jurjen</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="home">
  <div class="header">
      <a class="nav" href="#" id="home">Home</a>
      <a class="nav" href="#" id="about">About</a>
      <a class="nav" href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <img src="img/programmer1.png" alt="programmer"> 
  <a id="button" class="arrow bounce" href="#"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="about">
  <p class="P1">Waarom gebruiken we het? Het is al geruime tijd een bekend gegeven dat een lezer, tijdens het bekijken van de layout van een pagina, afgeleid wordt door de tekstuele inhoud. Het belangrijke punt van het gebruik van Lorem Ipsum is dat het uit een min of meer normale verdeling van letters bestaat, in tegenstelling tot "Hier uw tekst, hier uw tekst" wat het tot min of meer leesbaar nederlands maakt. Veel desktop publishing pakketten en web pagina editors gebruiken tegenwoordig Lorem Ipsum als hun standaard model tekst, en een zoekopdracht naar "lorem ipsum" ontsluit veel websites die nog in aanbouw zijn. Verscheidene versies hebben zich ontwikkeld in de loop van de jaren, soms per ongeluk soms expres (ingevoegde humor en dergelijke).</p>
 </div>
 <div class="contact">
  <p>Waarom gebruiken we het?Het is al geruime tijd een bekend gegeven dat een lezer, tijdens het bekijken van de layout van een pagina, afgeleid wordt door de tekstuele inhoud. Het belangrijke punt van het gebruik van Lorem Ipsum is dat het uit een min of meer normale verdeling van letters bestaat, in tegenstelling tot "Hier uw tekst, hier uw tekst" wat het tot min of meer leesbaar nederlands maakt. Veel desktop publishing pakketten en web pagina editors gebruiken tegenwoordig Lorem Ipsum als hun standaard model tekst, en een zoekopdracht naar "lorem ipsum" ontsluit veel websites die nog in aanbouw zijn. Verscheidene versies hebben zich ontwikkeld in de loop van de jaren, soms per ongeluk soms expres (ingevoegde humor en dergelijke).
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function() {
 $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".P1").offset().top},
     'slow');
});
$("#home").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".home").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
$("#about").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".about").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
$("#contact").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".contact").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
</script>
```

As you can see. when you click a nav button it does scroll but not to the top of the div it scrolls tho the middle of the div. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `offset().top` does not account for the height of the `.header` element, so the content is aligned underneath it.

To fix this simply retrieve the `outerHeight()` of `.header` and subtract it from `offset().top`.

Also note that you can DRY up the multiple click handlers by using a single selector to retrieve them all then targeting the element to scroll to by linking the `id` of the clicked `a` element. Try this:

```js
var navHeight = $('.header').outerHeight();

$(".header a").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("." + this.id).offset().top - navHeight
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #10171e;
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #15202b;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header-right {
  float: left;
}

.home {
  /*margin-bottom: 500px;*/
}

.about {
  background: red;
  /*height: 1000px;*/
  /*margin-top: 500px;*/
  /*margin-bottom: 500px;*/
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.contact {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1000px;
  /*margin-top: 500px;*/
  /*margin-bottom: 500px;*/
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}


}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="home">
  <div class="header">
    <a class="nav" href="#" id="home">Home</a>
    <a class="nav" href="#" id="about">About</a>
    <a class="nav" href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <img src="img/programmer1.png" alt="programmer">
  <a id="button" class="arrow bounce" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="about">
  <p class="P1">Waarom gebruiken we het? Het is al geruime tijd een bekend gegeven dat een lezer, tijdens het bekijken van de layout van een pagina, afgeleid wordt door de tekstuele inhoud. Het belangrijke punt van het gebruik van Lorem Ipsum is dat het uit een min
    of meer normale verdeling van letters bestaat, in tegenstelling tot "Hier uw tekst, hier uw tekst" wat het tot min of meer leesbaar nederlands maakt. Veel desktop publishing pakketten en web pagina editors gebruiken tegenwoordig Lorem Ipsum als hun
    standaard model tekst, en een zoekopdracht naar "lorem ipsum" ontsluit veel websites die nog in aanbouw zijn. Verscheidene versies hebben zich ontwikkeld in de loop van de jaren, soms per ongeluk soms expres (ingevoegde humor en dergelijke).</p>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <p>Waarom gebruiken we het?Het is al geruime tijd een bekend gegeven dat een lezer, tijdens het bekijken van de layout van een pagina, afgeleid wordt door de tekstuele inhoud. Het belangrijke punt van het gebruik van Lorem Ipsum is dat het uit een min
    of meer normale verdeling van letters bestaat, in tegenstelling tot "Hier uw tekst, hier uw tekst" wat het tot min of meer leesbaar nederlands maakt. Veel desktop publishing pakketten en web pagina editors gebruiken tegenwoordig Lorem Ipsum als hun
    standaard model tekst, en een zoekopdracht naar "lorem ipsum" ontsluit veel websites die nog in aanbouw zijn. Verscheidene versies hebben zich ontwikkeld in de loop van de jaren, soms per ongeluk soms expres (ingevoegde humor en dergelijke).
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How to write outerHeight in pure javascript?

Comment: @DogukanCavus see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787782/full-height-of-a-html-element-div-including-border-padding-and-margin

Comment: @J.vee no problem, glad to help