# How to "grow" parent to accommodate large children that use absolute positioning and z-index (overlay)?

Tags: html, css, overlay

Is there a way to create an overlay using absolute positioning and have the parent element "grow" to accommodate the children?
The problem is that the [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) removes items from the document flow, causing the floating elements with higher z-index to not only overlay the intended element, but also the elements following.

```css
#container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 1vw;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  
  /*height: 20vh;*/
 
}

#child1,
#child2 {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Before parent

  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      Child 1 should be in the background.
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      Child 2 should be in the foreground.<br> It covers Child 1 (overlay).<br> It is larger than Child 1.
    </div>
    Parent should grow to contain both children.
  </div>

  After parent
</div>
```

Comment: No, that is not possible in pure CSS alone. // Rather unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Normally, it is the _point_ of an actual overlay, that it sits above other content, and does not cause any interuptions in the normal flow.

Comment: as you said yourself, yes the parent can't see how big the children are and therefor cant grow to that size using css, but javascript can take care of this

Comment: this could be very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10787807/9496199

Answer (score 0):

Since it's being taken out of flow there is no way that the parent can know/respond to the child's dimensions with CSS alone. You can however use JS to accomplish what you're trying to do.

I also removed `height: 100%` for the child `div`'s as they weren't reflecting the true height of the space taken up by the child `div`'s contents.

```js
const checkSize = () =>{
  var childElSize = document.getElementById("child2").offsetHeight
  document.getElementById("parent").style.height = childElSize + 'px'
  console.log('Height: ' + childElSize + 'px')
}

checkSize()
```

```css
#container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 1vw;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  
  /*height: 20vh;*/
 
}

#child1,
#child2 {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Before parent

  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      Child 1 should be in the background.
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      Child 2 should be in the foreground.<br> It covers Child 1 (overlay).<br> It is larger than Child 1.
    </div>
    Parent should grow to contain both children.
  </div>

  After parent
</div>
```